# How to print request_body and response_body from NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-log

I want to print the request_body and response_body from NGINX.

I try to implement a few of the solution that I have learned from **[here](https://serverfault.com/questions/361556/is-it-possible-to-log-the-response-data-in-nginx-access-log)**

But it was not working in my case. Is there some additional changes that I need to configure in my **NGINX.conf** file.

Here is my conf file.

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream consumer-portal {
        server xx.xx.xx.xx:9006;
    }
     upstream download-zip-service {
        server xx.xx.xx.xx:9012;
    }
server {
        listen 8765;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://download-zip-service/;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            # proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            #socket timeout setting added
            fastcgi_read_timeout 7200s; 
            send_timeout 7200s;
            proxy_connect_timeout 7200s;
            proxy_send_timeout 7200s;
            proxy_read_timeout 7200s;
            #new property added
            proxy_request_buffering off;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }
        location /consumer-portal/ {
            proxy_pass         http://consumer-portal/;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ../../conf/sandbox/
    volumes:
    - ./mysite.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template
    ports:
    - "8765:8765"
    networks:
      - cloud


networks:
  cloud:
   driver: bridge
```

Please let me know what changes I need to configure.

Thanks In Advance.